# Как можно ускорить цикл в python?

Tags: python, циклы, for, скорость

У меня есть участок код, который надо ускорить до предела! Мне нужно заменить питоновкий цикл на более быстрый бесконечный цикл! Может есть библиотеки или методы включающие в себя другие способы бесконечного цикла?

```
from requests import get
from threading import Thread
def Dos(): 
    while True:
        with open("host.txt", 'r') as file:
            Host = file.read()
        res = get(Host)
while True:
    Thread(target=Dos).start()
```

Это программа для проверки на стойкость моих сайтов.

Comment: при работе с вводом/выводом нет большого смысла от многопоточности. уточните вашу задачу

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nxyiLiecC6M

Comment: У меня есть коде сами команды после print()ов, которые я просто не захотел вставлять. Но это вроде ничего не должно менять. Пусть задачей будет вывести как можно больше надписей.

Comment: Я сегодня уже видел [идентичный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1436230), ныне удалённый...

Comment: убери принт. Ускорится в разы. принт - очень медленная операция

Comment: from requests import get
    from threading import Thread
    from numba import njit
    @njit()
    def Dos(): 
        while True:
            with open("host.txt", 'r') as file:
                Host = file.read()
            res = get(Host)
   while True:
       Thread(target=Dos).start()

Поможет ли сейчас Numba?

Comment: Не стоит плодить аккаунты для обхода блокировки. Предполагается, что вы наведете порядок в первом аккаунте.

Comment: Задача которую вы решаете не ускорится если вы ускорите код Питона. Бутылочным горлышком будут сетевые обращения. Питон способен направить десятки тысяч запросов в секунду. Эти запросы забьют ваш сетевой интерфейс, канал провайдера и загрузят отвечающий сайт. Ускорять сам код в этой ситуации бесполезно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вывод в терминал - операция очень медленная, её можно ускорить только выкинув её вообще из кода.
А что касается "быстрого счёта до очень большой цифры", то тут хорошо помогает `Numba`.

Посмотрим, сколько считается до 100 миллионов без ухищрений:

```py
def test():
    for i in range(100_000_000):
        pass

%time test()
# Wall time: 2.77 s
```

А теперь тоже самое с `Numba`:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit()
def test():
    for i in range(100_000_000):
        pass

%time test()
# Wall time: 129 ms
```

Примерно в 20 раз быстрее.

А теперь напишем нереально большое число повторений цикла:

```py
from numba import njit

@njit()
def test():
    for i in range(1_000_000_000_000_000_000):
        pass

%time test()
# Wall time: 73.5 ms
```

Хм, ещё меньше времени понадобилось, хотя это в общем-то погрешности измерения.

Так что ускорить пустой цикл - не проблема. Вопрос в том, что именно вы хотите делать в этом цикле. Зачем выводить быстро надписи на терминал - непонятно. Кто их там будет читать с такой скоростью и в таком количестве? А если там простая арифметика какая-то, то с ней прекрасно справляется `Numba`.

P.S. Если поставить внутри цикла банальный счётчик `n += 1`, то чисто питоновский цикл замедлится в 3 раза, а цикл на `Numba` будет работать с такой же скоростью как и раньше и только на сверхбольших числах замедлится раза в 2.

Comment: Спасибо! А можно использовать так:
from numba import njit

@njit()
for _ in repeat(0):
    pass
Будут ли работать команды внутри for быстрее?

Comment: Декораторы работают только целиком на функцию. Конструкция `for _ repeat(0):` не имеет смысла - вы же не пользуетесь переменной цикла, поэтому проще и понятнее написать `while True:` для того же самого эффекта.

Comment: то есть numba работает и с while?

Comment: Да она много с чем работает, но если вы именно ускорение вывода хотите, то всё это без толку.

Comment: команда вместо принтов это - res = get("ссылка")

Comment: Так это совсем отдельный вопрос. Скорее всего вас просто сайт забанит или ограничит, который вы запросами засыпаете

Comment: Есть преположения как это ускорить, исключая бан от сайта? Я уже разберусь за банит или нет? Мне нужно возрастание скорости.

Comment: Попробуйте библиотеку `grequests`, например

Comment: спасибо, попробую